# Is it possible to use a TLC SSD like an SLC SSD?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, performance, storage

I’ve heard that MLC (and higher level, including TLC) SSDs are slower (when nearly full) and less reliable than SLC SSDs. The problem is that I can’t seem to find SLC SSDs available for sale today, and I’ve heard that they’re more expensive.

I’m wondering if I could avoid these problems by using only a fraction of the available capacity on a TLC drive. I’m thinking that if these drives only lose performance when nearly full, then at lower usages (1/2 for MLC, 1/3 for TLC, etc) these drives must function like SLC drives.

Assuming that this is the case, would using a little bit of space at the end (for backup partition tables) cause the end of the allocated space to function as MLC? Would I need to periodically TRIM the unused sections to remind the drive that only a fraction is being used? And would these behaviours depend on specific manufacturers and firmware, or is this standard across models?

Comment: I suspect performance for TLC/MLC/QLC drives is a bit more complicated than chip 'architecture' - stuff like cache and how some drives can have 'some' SLC or other non ram based cache and other things might work too. Some modern TLC drives are faster and can satuate a PCIe 3.0 x4 bus, and/or are limited by thermals, not other things.... so.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of 'half an answer' until someone smarter than me comes along with a better technical explanation…

SSDs don't respect partition or volume boundaries like on an HD. Basically they write to 'all of it' all the time.
you can see a practical example of this if you look at Apple's APFS structure, where any volume can be any size simply by growing & shrinking invisibly as needed, until the entire drive (or strictly container) is 'full'.

To take a simpler example - if you were to partition your drive right down the middle, say 500GB in two partitions of a 1TB drive, then write a large 500GB file to one partition, erase it then write it again, you would almost certainly have written to 'all' the drive, in terms of which specific cells have had data written to them. Even though you only used half your allocated space & only one of two partitions, the SSDs underlying structure doesn't care. It will write to the next unused block & let TRIM follow round afterwards to tidy up.

So whilst you can endeavour to always keep a drive half empty simply by partitioning it (as far as I'm aware no partitioning method other than APFS can set 'soft' boundaries), you cannot dictate where that 'half' is written. TRIM will endeavour to erase unused blocks in the background as needed, because writes are considerably faster than erase/writes.

Comment: In some sense - this sounds a lot like 'short stroking' spinning rust drives to get better performance.

Comment: I guess so - I've always worked on the 'keep *nn%* free so it has room to breathe', & never really got caught up in the technicalities. My *nn* does tend to be high, ⅓ free at least on all the SSDs here, even the big ones.

Comment: Your point about block device "locations" not necessarily corresponding to physical block locations is well taken, but I would still restrict usage via partitioning to ensure that some blocks are never written to (so that the SSD "knows" that they're not in use). I would also still place the partition at the beginning of the drive, in case the physical block location is calculated by mod-ing the block device location by the "SLC size". But I don't know much about SSD hardware so your answer is still appreciated.

Comment: SSDs just don't have a beginning & end, nor do they have really anything analogous to contiguous or physical blocks . The write controller doesn't care where you think you put a partition; that's just a GUI design style so humans can still think in HD terms that they do understand. Hence my simple experiment to prove that splitting a drive in half doesn't prevent the entire drive being written to. You have zero control over which "blocks" the drive uses.